# java pick random images

Tags: java, image, swing, random, paintcomponent

English is not my native language, sorry for any mistakes. I have to make a Bubble Shooter game in Java. I want to use images for the bubbles and I want the images to be picked randomly. I used `Random` and `ImageIcon` classes. My program doesn't show anything when I compile it and I don't know where the problem is. I'm a beginner in Java.

This is the code for my Game class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Game extends JPanel{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  //what the balls are like
  public final static int START_BALLS=40;
  public static Vector<Ball> balls = new Vector<Ball>();
  private Image img;
  private Graphics graphics;

  public Game() {
    for(int i=0; i<START_BALLS; i++) {
      balls.add(new Ball());
    }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    img = createImage(null);
    graphics = img.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(graphics);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    repaint();
  }

  public void paintComponet(Graphics g) {
    for(int i=0; i<balls.size(); i++) {
      Ball b=(Ball)balls.get(i);
      b.draw(g);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    new Frame();
    Game game = new Game();
    new Game();
    Window.window.add(game);
  }
}
```

and the class for the bubbles:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Ball {
  Random random = new Random();
  final String[] image_paths = new String[] {"balls/peg_0.png",
            "balls/peg_1.png","balls/peg_2.png","balls/peg_3.png",
            "balls/peg_4.png","balls/peg_5.png"};

  String randomBalls;
  public Image image;

  public Ball(){
    randomBalls = image_paths[random.nextInt(image_paths.length)];
    ImageIcon poza = new ImageIcon(randomBalls);
    image=poza.getImage();
  }

  public void draw(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null, null);
  }
}
```

What is wrong with my program?

Comment: The code works if you just put the filename without the randomness? Because there is nothing obviously wrong with what you have here.

Comment: The main method seems a bit weird to me too. Shouldn't be something like Frame frame = new Frame(); frame.add(game); ? Without creating two instances of Game class?

Comment: can someone give me an example of the paint method,how it shoul look like?i know that is maybe a stupid question,but i don't know how to do it.thanks for all your answers

Comment: Those 'answers' are comments.  See my [actual answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21026597/418556) that shows a working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look over my comments, look carefully at the comments in the code, see how I rearranged the organization of the classes.

[image: Game demo]

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.net.URL;

public class Game extends JPanel {

    Random random = new Random();
    final String[] image_path = new String[]{
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png",
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHARa.png",
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png",
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5uTa.png"
    };
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    //what the balls are like
    public final static int START_BALLS = 40;
    public static Vector<Ball> balls = new Vector<Ball>();
    private Image img;
    // A Graphics instance is typically transient.
    // There is rarely, if ever, a need to store them
    //private Graphics graphics;

    public Game() {
        for (int i = 0; i < image_path.length; i++) {
            balls.add(new Ball(image_path[i]));
        }
        //I have no idea what you were trying to achieve here, but it fails horribly
        // img = createImage(null);
        img = new BufferedImage(100, 100, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        // graphics = img.getGraphics();
        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(400, al);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override  // very handy!
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);  A JPanel IS A ImageObserver
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        Ball b = (Ball) balls.get(random.nextInt(4));
        b.draw(g);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Game");
                f.add(new Game());
                // Ensures JVM closes after frame(s) closed and
                // all non-daemon threads are finished
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556 for demo.
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                // ensures the frame is the minimum size it needs to be
                // in order display the components within it
                f.pack();
                // should be done last, to avoid flickering, moving,
                // resizing artifacts.
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        // Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT
        // http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class Ball {

    String randomBalls;
    public Image image;

    public Ball(String url) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new URL(url));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null, null);
    }
}
```

### Tips

- `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getGraphics() not valid for images created with createImage(producer) at img = createImage(null);` I have no idea what you thought that code statement does, but ..nothing good.
- When doing custom painting in a `JPanel`, we should override only `paintComponent(Graphics)` and leave the `paint(Graphics)` method as it is. When overriding the former, immediately call the super method.
- Adding a call to `repaint()` inside `paint(Graphics)` will cause an infinite loop.. If the code needs to loop, establish a Swing Timer to call `repaint()`
- `paintComponet(Graphics g)` should be `paintComponent(Graphics g)`  Use `@Override` notation when appropriate.  It would have warned you of the incorrectly spelled method name.

### More general tips

1. For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
2. One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).
3. By the time of deployment, those images will likely become an [embedded-resource](/questions/tagged/embedded-resource).  That being the case, they must be accessed by `URL` instead of `File`.  See the [info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for the tag, for a way to form an `URL`.