# Displaying background image with java nullpointerexception

Tags: java, image, nullpointerexception

My goal right now is to set a background image with "black.png".

```
package testing;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class test extends Panel {
    test Panel;
    Image background;

    //image loading
    public void paint(Graphics bg) {
        bg.drawImage(background, 20, 20, null);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Image background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("black.png");
        test panel = new test();
        panel.paint(null);
    }
}
```

and the output :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at testing.test.paint(test.java:10)
>   at testing.test.main(test.java:16)

Why doesn't line 10 and 16 point to null? And is it possible to just display a black background then overlay images that I want to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @raul1ro i did but it says file cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: @xxboomxx, are you trying to achieve this using JFrame?

Comment: @Nicholas K actually yes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java pick random images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025595/java-pick-random-images)

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly passing `null` into your `paint()` method on line 16.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: @xxboomxx pass initialized `Graphics` instance instead. `Graphics gr = panel.getGraphics();` for example